# Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

***Вот текст задачи:***
Напишите простой калькулятор, который считывает с пользовательского ввода три строки: первое число, второе число и операцию, после чего применяет операцию к введённым числам ("первое число" "операция" "второе число") и выводит результат на экран.

Поддерживаемые операции: +, -, /, *, mod, pow, div, где
mod — это взятие остатка от деления,
pow — возведение в степень,
div — целочисленное деление.

Если выполняется деление и второе число равно 0, необходимо выводить строку "Деление на 0!".

Обратите внимание, что на вход программе приходят вещественные числа.

***А вот мой код:***

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
operation = input()
if operation == "mod":
    if b == 0.0:
        print("Деление на 0!")
    else:
        print(a % b)
if operation == "div":
    if b == 0.0:
        print("Деление на 0!")
    else:
        print(a / b)
if operation == "/":
    if b == 0.0:
        print("Деление на 0!")
    else:
        print(a / b)
elif operation == "+":
    print(a + b)
elif operation == "-":
    print(a - b)
elif operation == "*":
    print(a * b)
elif operation == "pow":
    print(a ** b)
```

Comment: Все правильно. Тока все кроме первого ифа на элифы поменяй ;)

Comment: А что не работает?

Comment: div — целочисленное деление. ошибка print(a / b)

Answer (score 0):

ваша ошибка print(a / b). div — целочисленное деление обозначается //

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
operation = input()
if operation == "mod":
    if b == 0.0:
        print("Деление на 0!")
    else:
        print(a % b)
elif operation == "div":
    if b == 0.0:
        print("Деление на 0!")
    else:
        print(a // b)
elif operation == "/":
    if b == 0.0:
        print("Деление на 0!")
    else:
        print(a / b)
elif operation == "+":
    print(a + b)
elif operation == "-":
    print(a - b)
elif operation == "*":
    print(a * b)
elif operation == "pow":
    print(a ** b)
```